# ASP Web Api + Android Retrofit. Ошибка при получении JSON

Tags: java, android, retrofit, asp.net-web-api, gson

Имеется:

- Приложение Android
- Web API на ASP.NET

Создаю объект `Retrofit`:

```
Retrofit service = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("http://192.168.0.3/") // адрес WebApi
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
    .build();
```

В коде вызываю нужный мне метод API, в API данные приходят корректно.
В качестве теста возвращаю пришедшую в контроллер модель в `json`

**Action**

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetUser(UserModel model)
{
    return Json(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model));
}
```

**Model**

```
public class UserModel
{
    [JsonProperty("id")]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("password")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("name")]
    public string name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("device_id")]
    public string DeviceId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("register_date")]
    public string RegisterDate { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("updated_date")]
    public string UpdatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Через POSTMAN получаю корректный `json`.
Однако в Android получаю `Exception`:

```
com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:224)
     at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:37)
     at retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonResponseBodyConverter.convert(GsonResponseBodyConverter.java:25)
     at retrofit2.ServiceMethod.toResponse(ServiceMethod.java:117)
     at retrofit2.OkHttpCall.parseResponse(OkHttpCall.java:211)
     at retrofit2.OkHttpCall$1.onResponse(OkHttpCall.java:106)
     at okhttp3.RealCall$AsyncCall.execute(RealCall.java:133)
     at okhttp3.internal.NamedRunnable.run(NamedRunnable.java:32)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
 Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $
     at com.google.gson.stream.JsonReader.beginObject(JsonReader.java:385)
     at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.read(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:213)
    ... 10 more
```

Почему на Android не парсится `json` пришедший с API?

**UPD**
Ответ от API:

```
{\"id\":1,\"email\":\"myemail@gmail.com\",\"password\":\"1234\",\"name\":null,\"device_id\":null,\"register_date\":null,\"updated_date\":null}
```

В Android в обработчике callback вываливаюсь сюда:

```
@Override
public void onFailure(Call<UserModel> call, Throwable t) {
    t.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Покажите ответ от сервера, Json, им возвращаемый. Наверное вам надо немного модель данных изменить

Comment: @ЮрийСПб добавил в вопрос

Comment: Кмк это не JSON. По моему все экранирующие слэши - лишние

Comment: @ЮрийСПб что значит "не JSON"? чем вам мешают слеши? ответ может быть и так, но сути это не меняет, ошибка все равно есть: `{"id":0,"email":"myemail@gmail.com","password":"1234","name":null,"device_id":null,"register_date":null,"updated_date":null}`

Comment: Вот этот валидатор говорит что это не JSON https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ А вот аналогичный вопрос: http://stackoverflow.com/q/33043211/3212712 - также советуют убрать слэши

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да, посмотрел, я не прав

Comment: Т.е. убирание слэшей помогло? Если нет - покажите модель на клиентской стороне, на Java

Comment: @ЮрийСПб да, после убирания слешей я перестал вываливать в `onFailure`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Согласно этому [валидатору](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/) в ответе сервера невалидный JSON - лишние экранирующие слэши. Вот [здесь](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33043211/3212712) описывают аналогичную проблему и советуют убрать экранирующие слэши